# Vector notation for shifting the elements of a vector

Tags: matrices, notation, vectors

I'm looking for a suitable notation to express a "shift operator" which shifts  all elements of a vector forward and sets the first element to zero, e.g., 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
(1,1,0,1) & \rightarrow & (0,1,1,0),\\
(0,1,1,1) & \rightarrow & (0,0,1,1).
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make one with a 4x4 matrix. Call it S or something.
\begin{array}{l}
\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{S_{00}}}&{{S_{01}}}&{{S_{02}}}&{{S_{03}}}\\
{{S_{10}}}&{{S_{11}}}&{{S_{12}}}&{{S_{13}}}\\
{{S_{20}}}&{{S_{21}}}&{{S_{22}}}&{{S_{23}}}\\
{{S_{30}}}&{{S_{31}}}&{{S_{32}}}&{{S_{33}}}
\end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
a\\
b\\
c\\
d
\end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0\\
a\\
b\\
c
\end{array}} \right)\\
\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{S_{00}}a + {S_{01}}b + {S_{02}}c + {S_{03}}d}\\
{{S_{10}}a + {S_{11}}b + {S_{12}}c + {S_{13}}d}\\
{{S_{20}}a + {S_{21}}b + {S_{22}}c + {S_{23}}d}\\
{{S_{30}}a + {S_{31}}b + {S_{32}}c + {S_{33}}d}
\end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0\\
a\\
b\\
c
\end{array}} \right)\\
\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{S_{00}}}&{{S_{01}}}&{{S_{02}}}&{{S_{03}}}\\
{{S_{10}}}&{{S_{11}}}&{{S_{12}}}&{{S_{13}}}\\
{{S_{20}}}&{{S_{21}}}&{{S_{22}}}&{{S_{23}}}\\
{{S_{30}}}&{{S_{31}}}&{{S_{32}}}&{{S_{33}}}
\end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0
\end{array}} \right)
\end{array}

For n-dimensions...

$$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0&0&0&0&{...}&0_n\\
1&0&0&{...}&0&0\\
0&1&0&{...}&0&0\\
0&0&1&{...}&0&0\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0&0&0& \cdots &1&0_n
\end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{v_1}}\\
{{v_2}}\\
{{v_3}}\\
 \vdots \\
{{v_n}}
\end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0\\
{{v_1}}\\
{{v_2}}\\
 \vdots \\
{{v_{n - 1}}}
\end{array}} \right)
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% faaagCart1ev2aaaKnaaaaWenf2ys9wBH5garuavP1wzZbqedmvETj
% 2BSbqefm0B1jxALjharqqtubsr4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0x
% bbL8FesqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaq
% pepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-xfr-xb9Gqpi0dc9adbaqaaeGaciGa
% aiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaWaaeWaaeaafaWabeGbgaaaaaqaaiaaic
% daaeaacaaIWaaabaGaaGimaaqaaiaaicdaaeaacaGGUaGaaiOlaiaa
% c6caaeaacaaIWaaabaGaaGymaaqaaiaaicdaaeaacaaIWaaabaGaai
% Olaiaac6cacaGGUaaabaGaaGimaaqaaiaaicdaaeaacaaIWaaabaGa
% aGymaaqaaiaaicdaaeaacaGGUaGaaiOlaiaac6caaeaacaaIWaaaba
% GaaGimaaqaaiaaicdaaeaacaaIWaaabaGaaGymaaqaaiaac6cacaGG
% UaGaaiOlaaqaaiaaicdaaeaacaaIWaaabaGaeSO7I0eabaGaeSO7I0
% eabaGaeSO7I0eabaGaeSy8I8eabaGaeSO7I0eabaGaeSO7I0eabaGa
% aGimaaqaaiaaicdaaeaacaaIWaaabaGaeS47IWeabaGaaGymaaqaai
% aaicdaaaaacaGLOaGaayzkaaWaaeWaaeaafaqabeqbbaaaaeaacaWG
% 2bWaaSbaaSqaaiaaigdaaeqaaaGcbaGaamODamaaBaaaleaacaaIYa
% aabeaaaOqaaiaadAhadaWgaaWcbaGaaG4maaqabaaakeaacqWIUlst
% aeaacaWG2bWaaSbaaSqaaiaad6gaaeqaaaaaaOGaayjkaiaawMcaai
% abg2da9maabmaabaqbaeqabuqaaaaabaGaaGimaaqaaiaadAhadaWg
% aaWcbaGaaGymaaqabaaakeaacaWG2bWaaSbaaSqaaiaaikdaaeqaaa
% GcbaGaeSO7I0eabaGaamODamaaBaaaleaacaWGUbGaeyOeI0IaaGym
% aaqabaaaaaGccaGLOaGaayzkaaaaaa!704D!
$$